# PST PidLidAttendeeCriticalChange property

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi, pst

Have come across a scenario where using Outlook Spy I can see that my msg has the above said property. But once i export the pst and try to extract this message, this property does not exist in the expecte location i.e. 0x0001 index and offset 0x0040.
However in outlook spy i see a tag num of 0x80B00040 and sure enough when I look at the property mappings i see in tag 0x80B0 i.e. this value.
My question is that where does this tag value come from ? I do not find any references to it here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237112(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237112%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) ?

Can someone also explain the relation between named property and tags ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "this property does not exist in the expecte location i.e. 0x0001 index and offset 0x0040."?

Do you mean the property tag changes? This is to be expected - the mappings between GUID//id and the prop tag are store specific. You should always call IMAPIProp::GetIDsFromNames on an object from the desired store to figure out the property tag.

Comment: Sorry was not clear. I am using a java library jpst to kind of parse the pst. Their representation of the named property table use as index the LID (in the link) which is 0x00000001 to fetch a property Id. In order to form the property tag it left shifts this value by 16 and adds as offset the the datatype 0x0040 to fetch the value from a table entry structure. I was under the impression that this would be some sort of generic algo to convert propertyId to tags and fetching the corresponding values.

Comment: So you are reading a PST file on the binary level? I don't have any experience with that, sorry.

Comment: would you happen to be able to provide pointers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23799316/720571